# Unable to input/select options from Command Prompt

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

[image]

I am trying Firebase Functions in my app. As I go through the process I findout It works from Command Prompt.But I am unable to select options or enter inputs into the prompt.After executing the command it just terminates.
Ex: I have to input Y/n but it just terminated.

Please Help

Comment: Please edit the question to show the contents of firebase-debug.log that is being referenced in the error message you see in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Rerun firebase installation:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save

npm install -g firebase-tools
```

then

```
firebase login
```

then

```
firebase init
```

Comment: It didn't helped me.I think there is something wrong with Command Prompt